# Unable to make Resharper (or VS 2019) formats switch statements the way I want

Tags: c#, resharper, visual-studio-2019

I'm making use of Resharper's auto-code-reformat capabilities but I cannot figure out how to make it (or Visual Studio, for that matter) place lines the way I want in a switch statement.  Can point me to the setting I need to make this happen?

(FYI: I'm using the latest Resharper and Visual Studio 2019)

Say I start with the following C# code block:

```
if (TargetContext is BgaContext bga)
{
    Status = Strings.FindingBgaCircles;
    bga.FindCirclesAndUpdateScan(ResolutionMmpp, CancellationToken);
}
else if (TargetContext is GrooveContext groove)
{
    Status = Strings.FindingGrooveLine;
    groove.FindLineAndUpdateScan(ResolutionMmpp, CancellationToken);
}
```

Resharper gives me the option to make it into a "switch" statement so I take advantage of it.  Once it's done changing the code, I see this:

```
switch (TargetContext)
{
case BgaContext bga:
    Status = Strings.FindingBgaCircles;
    bga.FindCirclesAndUpdateScan(ResolutionMmpp, CancellationToken);

    break;
case GrooveContext groove:
    Status = Strings.FindingGrooveLine;
    groove.FindLineAndUpdateScan(ResolutionMmpp, CancellationToken);

    break;
}
```

But I don't want the extra line before the "break" and I *do* want a line after it.  In other words, I want Resharper to make it look like this:

```
switch (TargetContext)
{
case BgaContext bga:
    Status = Strings.FindingBgaCircles;
    bga.FindCirclesAndUpdateScan(ResolutionMmpp, CancellationToken);
    break;

case GrooveContext groove:
    Status = Strings.FindingGrooveLine;
    groove.FindLineAndUpdateScan(ResolutionMmpp, CancellationToken);
    break;
}
```

I've tried going through every Resharper C# formatting setting one-by-one and I can't find one that affects it.  I've searched the settings for the words "switch", "case", and "break" but none of them seems to affect how it laces the lines.  I've done the same thing for Visual Studio, still no-joy.

I'm sure this must be right in front of me and I'm just missing it.  Is there a settings somewhere that will give me what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To learn about formatting settings affecting your code, select the small piece of code, press `Alt-Enter` and select `Format selection > Configure`. For example, to learn settings affecting blank lines between two lines of code, select piece of code starting from the last character of the first line of code and ending with the first character of the second line of code.

Also, starting from ReSharper 2018.3 you can also ask ReSharper to detect formatting settings automatically. Select the piece of code, press `Alt-Enter` and select `Format selection > Detect formatting settings`.

In ReSharper 2019.1 you need to set the following settings to get the desired formatting:

- `Blank lines > Blank Lines in Code > Before statements with control transfer` = 0
- `Blank lines > Blank Lines in Code > Before "case" in switch statement` = 1